# Как зафиксировать размер видимой части экрана без выходящих за края CSS в адаптив под мобильные

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Когда по макету из фигмы есть половинчатые блоки, которые не вписываются в общую систему адаптивности. Например https://www.figma.com/file/8T4byFDAV5REmnVyQlsFO1/clean_and_simple_website_freebie_work_file?node-id=3%3A2 Такой пример часто встречается когда содержимое вылазиет за границы отображаемые в видимой части. Чуть ниже середины лендинга половинчатый блок выходит за область видимой части. https://nasobe.ru/figma-simple-website.html#invisible
Вся проблема в том что на некоторых устройствах или браузерах фиксируется max-width: 100%; и затрагивает выпирающий блок, так что он явно выпирает и вмещается в область видимости.
Когда дело касается мобильной адаптивности!
Есть ли какой нибудь способ зафиксировать ширину дисплея чтобы выпирающиеся блоки не фиксировали max-width:100%; при прописаном вьюпорте(под мобильные)?
Заранее большое спасибо! Успешных дел и хорошего настроения.(and_Мобильной адаптивности).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам стоит использовать `overflow:hidden` для родительского элемента
(блок, сразу после вашего комментария 'место где вылазит блок')

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).